# Split long column into matrix

Tags: excel, vba

I have a single column of half-hourly data (single numerical value) for a year and need split it into a 365x48 matrix. Is there a simple way to achieve this in Excel/VBA?

Comment: Do you want each row to represent a day and each column to represent a time or the other wau around ???

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned that. Rows as days and columns to represent the time

Answer (score 1):

With data in column **A** starting at **A2**, in **C2** enter:

```
=INDEX($A2:$A999999,COLUMNS($A:A)+48*(ROWS($1:1)-1),0)
```

copy first across and then downward.

[image]